# Python string formatting trim float precision to no more than needed

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

What's the best way to convert a float to a string with no more precision than needed to represent the number, and never more than a specified upper limit precision such that the following would happen?

```
>>> values = [1, 1., 1.01, 1.00000000001, 1.123456789, 100.123456789]
>>> print([ my_func(value,precision=6) for value in values]) 
['1', '1', '1.01', '1', '1.123457', '100.123457']
```

I've looked through `str.format`, but can only find methods for a specific precision that could include too many zeros:

```
>>> '{:0.6f}'.format(1.0)
'1.000000'
```

The `g` option comes close, but you have to do funny things based on the length of the integer part:

```
def my_func(value,precision=6):
    return '{v:0.{p}g}'.format(v=value,p=precision+len('{:d}'.format(int(value))))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `rstrip`-ing the `str.format` version do what you want? E.g.,

```
'{:0.6f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Comment: Ah! Didn't think of that one. Apparently you can combine `.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')'` into `.rstrip('0.')`

Comment: Watch out! Consider the number 100.0: this becomes "1" using the combined method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in option, but you could just use `string.rstrip` to remove the trailing zeros from the normal string representation of the float.

EDIT: You would also need to format it to the fixed maximum precision using the %f formatting token before using `string.rstrip`.